# multitouch support for magic mouse on further releases?

Tags: multi-touch, support, magic-mouse

In older questions on internet i found that the magic-mouse multitouch-support should work since 11.04. Now we have 11.10 and i didn't find any news, that here is a multitouch-support planned for 12.04.
Also the official touch-homepage doesn't says anything about a planned support for this device.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/HardwareSupport

Does anyone knows more? Is there hope for multitouch-support of magic-mouse in further releases?? Does anyone knows concrete plans?

I own this mouse and it supports only:
- one finger 
- vertical/horizontal scroll
- right, left and middle - click

This mouse is very useful and it could be much more if it would be supported like the apple magic trackpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu does not have a driver or any compatibility written in yet. That is the most basic answer there is. Someone might have written a driver for the magic mouse, but I haven't seen any drivers yet. 12.04 will probably have support for it since it is a LTS, so there is hope.

Also the reason it only supports basic functions is because that is all that is written for it, since the average mouse only has those features.